# Проверка на транзитивность, рефлексивность и симетричность матрицы в Python

Tags: python

```
A = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12]]
```

Вот у меня есть матрица, моя проблема состоит в том, что я понимаю транзитивность на множествах, но не могу понять как это работает на матрице. Хочу разобратся с этим, так как это важное задание и основное в понимании дискретной математики.